# Where should a linux binary be located to be called via ProcessBuilder/Runtime within a Spring Boot Microservice running in PCF

Tags: java, spring, runtime, processbuilder, cloud-foundry

I am trying to call a linux binary in a Spring Boot REST Controller via Runtime or ProcessBuilder
If I call built-in functions like **"ls -la"**, it works fine in PCF.

However, I get an error, when I call my binary using the absolute path location like so:
`Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\temp\\testbinary\\mybináry");`
The error is:
`Cannot run program "C:\temp\testbinary\mybinary": error=2, No such file or directory`
If I call the REST Endpoint locally, it runs but says my command is not a Win32 Application, which is fine.
So apparently PCF cannot access the local filesystem when the REST Endpoint is invoked which is logical.
So does it mean I need an external storage for my binary location and as well as file input parameters? And what alternatives are there please?

Is it possible to package the binary with the Spring Boot Jar File together? And if yes, how do I access the binary within the Microservice after deployment on PCF?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I get an error, when I call my binary using the absolute path location like so: Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\temp\testbinary\mybináry");

Using the absolute path is fine, you just need to use the path relative to the container where your app is running, not your local developer workstation's path.

When your app is deployed, it will be in `/home/vcap/app` or `/app` (symlink to the former). You can hard code the path or you can use `$HOME` or `$PWD` which are env variables that essentially point to the same location.

You might also be able to just use a relative path. The current working directory will be `/home/vcap/app`, so you could try that too.

> Is it possible to package the binary with the Spring Boot Jar File together? And if yes, how do I access the binary within the Microservice after deployment on PCF?

Yes, and that is exactly what you need to do to make this work. You would build your native executable & copy that to somewhere within your Java app. I think putting it into `src/main/resources` (or a sub directory) would be OK, but you could put it somewhere else too (so long as it's not publicly accessible where a user could download the binary).

After that, just change your process builder command to reference the location of where you've included the app.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This sounds good and promising! I will try the directives and feedback here.

Comment: I can access my binary with input file as parameter if I place both under `src\main\resources`.
Then they are located under `$HOME/BOOT-INF/classes` after pushing the `jar` file, and nowhere else. 

I can then call the binary like so:
`cd $HOME/BOOT-INF/classes; ./binary inputFile`. The generated file is put in the `classes` directory.

**Is there an environment variable for PCF to access the `classes` directory of the deployt java app?**. The `$HOME/BOOT-INF` is too volatile to use in code.
If not is there any best practice to solve this issue?

Comment: The files are not uploaded in the Cloud Foundry container if I put them in the root directory where `cf push` is called, like I read in other contributions.
I guess it is because the `path` for `cf push` specifies only the `jar` artefact?

Comment: `Is there an environment variable for PCF to access the classes directory of the deployt java app?` -> You could adjust `$PATH` to include that location. There's nothing CF specific though. For what it's worth, I doubt that path is going to change on you. It's the way Spring Boot creates it's JAR files, so it should be pretty stable. If you want it at a different location, you would have to move the file in your app.

Comment: `I guess it is because the path for cf push specifies only the jar artefact?` -> Correct. With Java apps, you push the compiled artifacts, not the source. That's why you point to the JAR/WAR file.

Comment: That will suffice for now. Your answers always point the way ahead. Thanks for your engagement and support